# Direct requests from location /projects to a different root, Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Nginx is setup to proxy my node server 9200 to port 80, the root is setup to serve `mypath/to/node_build`. I want to upload some static files though to the `/projects`.

So I do `location /projects { root /mypath/to/static_projects}` but I am getting a 404 error.

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/example.io/public_html/dist;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://example.io
        server_name example.io;
        server_name app.example.io;

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires 1y;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location ^~ /blog {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /projects {
           root /var/www/example.io/public_html/projects;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_disable “msie6″;


        #error_page 404 /404.html;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a location block matching /... nginx will continue to match other blocks -- see: [nginx docs on "location"](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location):

```
location  / {
  # matches any query, since all queries begin with /, but regular
  # expressions and any longer conventional blocks will be
  # matched first.
  [ configuration B ] 
}

location /documents/ {
  # matches any query beginning with /documents/ and continues searching,
  # so regular expressions will be checked. This will be matched only if
  # regular expressions don't find a match.
  [ configuration C ] 
}
```

So if you have another block above matching static files (`\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$`), these will end up using your default `root`.

What you can do is put a location block inside your `/projects` block to handle the static files or create a new location block with a regexp matching the static files with a path starting with `/projects`.

```
location /projects {
    root /var/www/example.io/public_html/projects;
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 1y;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}

# or:

location ~* ^/projects/.+\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    root /var/www/example.io/public_html/projects;
    expires 1y;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: Oh okay so that was the issue, eh. I will get back to the configuration soon and post back the result and a check.